# How to see svn log from the directory .svn?

Tags: svn

I used svn a long time ago.
I came across a directory containing a .svn directory.
Is there an utility that allows me to see the log?
Or what should I install?

Thanks

Comment: A svn directory might be readable by the svn tool. Have you tried `svn log`?

Comment: I tried with tortoisesvn but it asked for a server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer